# Why did div with no content be influenced by child elements

Tags: html, css, sass, compass-sass

I tried out to do some css3 animation with compass(sass framework).
I found accidentally that div with no content will be influenced.
The following is my sample code

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Sass

```
@import "compass/css3"

.box
    width: 600px
    height: 600px
    background-color: pink
    .ball
        width: 40px
        height: 40px
        +border-radius(100%)
        background-color: black
        margin-top: 50px  // How to just margin top the ball div
```

The result is looking like this. The div.box was following the ball.div margin top 200px, but I want it stay on the top of the page.

[image]

But when I add some content into div.box, the result is perform well but with some superfluous content.

```
<div class="box">0
    <div class="ball"></div>
    <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

I curiously why did div with no content be influenced by child elements, and how to deal with it.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. You added text content somewhere, and now you wonder that it is shown as text content ... why?

Comment: I want to do the same effect but with no content in the base div

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] somewhere so that we can look at the issue live.

Comment: I have revised my question. Thank you for advising.

Comment: Your research term is _collapsing margins_.

Comment: I have resolve it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to @CBroe's comment.
This is a problem call [**Collapsing margins**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

The problem occurs when:

1. Inner and outer elements are both display as block.
2. There are no **border**, **padding**, and **overflow** attributes been set on outer elements.
3. The position of first/last child of outer elements is not setting as float or absolute and remaining the content is blank.

The first/last child's border will be merged to it's parents.

The following code will solve the problem

```
.box
    overflow: auto // Set overflow attribute to outer element
    height: 600px
    background-color: pink
    .ball
        width: 40px
        height: 40px
        +border-radius(100%)
        background-color: black
        margin-top: 50px
```